# In the event of a "no-result found" scenario in Express, how can i output my choice error message to the browser without displaying an empty array []

Tags: javascript, express

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Questionnaire = require('../models/questionnaire');




router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 Questionnaire.find().sort('username').exec(function(error, results) {
 if (error) {
 return next(error);
 }
 // Respond with valid data
 res.json(results);
 });
 });
 router.get('/:questionnaireId', function(req, res, next){
Questionnaire
.where({username: req.params.questionnaireId}, {featured: true})
.where({featured: true})
.exec(function(error, results){
 if (error) {
 return next(error);
 }
 if (!results) {
res.send(404);
}
res.json(results);
});
});
```

module.exports = router;

In the event of a "no-result found" scenario in Express, how can i output my choice error message to the browser without displaying an empty array []. Each time i run a query with Express framework, my browser always displays this empty array [] when result is not found or user not found. How can i get around this?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer works or if you get the `if` condition right, then what is it so i can update. It could be `if (!results.length)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[...]

if (error) {
  return next(error);
}

// Check for empty results
if (!results.length) {
  results = { ... }; //custom response object
}

// Respond with valid data
res.json(results);

[...]
```

Comment: Waoh! I tried the other commented out option "if(!results.length) and it worked like magic. For once i could see my custom error message sent to the browser. Now wondering why it couldn't work with just if(!results). Mtz, you just brought meaning back into my programming life. A million thanks. Buy why didn't it work with the former option. Cheers

Comment: You're very welcome :) The first one didn't work because `results` is an array so it's truthy even if empty: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/ - hence this condition which checks the array length. I updated my answer, thanks!